# Selecting a particular photo from the multiple selected photos in HTML 5 Multi File Upload

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am using multiple file upload of HTML 5 and Code Igniter

```
<input type="file" name="image_file[]" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelected();" multiple />
```

But after selecting the multiple images I want to give a form in which the user will be displayed all the selected images along with a radio button for each image , means he can select any one of these photos to be displayed in "profile" and remaining photos will go to the "ALBUMS".

I am able to upload the multiple photos  but i am unable to selct any one of the photos from the selected photos . How Can i do this

Comment: What have you already tried? Do you want the images to be uploaded first?

Comment: Very simply. Once the upload action complete forward the user to an action which reads the list of files are draw a grid on a view and display the images

Comment: No I want to select the PROFILE image before uploading